# foreach loop inside foreach loop

Tags: php, loops

i have some code that opens an ftp server then inserts data into an database based on what files are in there

my problem is that it appears that `$fname2` is just calling the first file as the variable and keeps using that instead of looping through all the filenames

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
$unalteredcontents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);

foreach( $contents as $fname )
{
    if (($fname != '.')  && ($fname != '..') )
    {
        foreach ($unalteredcontents as $fname2)
        {
            if (($fname2 != '.') && ($fname2 !='..'))
            {
                $url = "http://website/userid/".$uid."/".$fname2."";
            }
        }
```

the `$fname2` is returning the first file as the variable for the whole loop
any insight?

Comment: You are assigning the value to `$url` each time the loop runs, but you don't do anything with that value. When the loop exits, it will hold the last value for `$fname2`.  What do you intend to use `$url` for?

Comment: the $url is called in the include file in the later parts of the loop

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Here's my test code:

```
<?php
// set up basic connection
$ftp_server = "ftp.yoursite.com";
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$dir = "./public_html/cgi-bin"; // just a sample directory
$uid = 1;

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);
$unalteredcontents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $dir);

foreach( $contents as $fname )
{
    if (($fname != '.')  && ($fname != '..') )
    {
        foreach ($unalteredcontents as $fname2)
        {
            if (($fname2 != '.') && ($fname2 !='..'))
            {
                echo "http://website/userid/".$uid."/".$fname2."\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I closed out your brackets and explicitly created the ftp-related variables.

It's hard to know what's going on in your particular instance. I assume your sure there is indeed more than one file in the directory in question?